# apt-get permission error on node.js setup

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, apt

I am trying to install node.js 7 on ubuntu. on running the command

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | bash -
```

or

```
sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | bash -
```

i get the following error:

```
## Installing the NodeSource Node.js v7.x repo...


## Populating apt-get cache...

+ apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
Error executing command, exiting
```

I have also run:

```
apt-get update
```

this again results in the error above, however when i run `sudo apt-get update`
there is no error but again on running the first two commands give error again.

i have tried to `autoremove` `purge` and `upgrade` but still the problem persists.
any help will be much appreciate

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By running

```
sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | bash -
```

You were running bash as yourself, and curl as root.and the owner of the bash process (you) didn't have rights to write to /var/lib/apt/lists/partial.
You can try using :

```
sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo bash  -
```

You can check this [article](https://gist.github.com/btm/6700524) for more information.

Comment: If you are using zsh you have to switch to bash shell manually before running the second command, otherwise the setup can't be executed